# How to map c code to postgres c function format?

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm trying to write the following c code in postgres c function style -
The argument passed is a value of a table column of type varchar,
Needed some help to map this pure C code in the postgres C format of the type -

Datum
func_name (PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)

Can somebody please help to map this and return the appropriate char value?

```
static uint32_t key = 0xOQ9426YP;
uint32_t tmpKey = 0x00000000;
int i = 0;
uint32_t *in = (uint32_t *) str;
uint32_t *out = (uint32_t *) malloc (256);
memset (out, 0, 256);
tmpKey = key;
for (i = 0; i < (256/sizeof (uint32_t));  i++)
{
    out[i] = tmpKey ^ in[i];
    tmpKey = out[i];
}
memcpy (output, (char *) out, 256);
```

Thanks & Regards,
VJ

Comment: This code completely ignores endianness.  Is that your intention?

Comment: On top of that, `0xOQ9426YP` is not a valid hexadecimal literal.

Answer (score 1):

For data PostgreSQL uses own internal format and structures that should not be compatible with C language. For strings a `varlena` format is used - in this format first N bytes are encoded length - and after these bytes are encoded data. The direct access is not recommended - for almost all work there are a macros.

For example - some small function `hello` can looks like:

```
Datum
Hello(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    text *txt = PG_GETARG_TEXT_PP(0);
    text *result;
    char *str;
    char *hello = "Hello, ";
    int   size;
    int   hello_size;

    -- conversion to c string
    str = text_to_cstring(txt);

    -- show it on debug console
    elog(NOTICE, "input string: %s", str);

    hello_size = strlen(hello); 
    size = hello_size + VARSIZE_ANY_EXHDR(txt) + VARHDRSZ;

    -- allocate memory for result, use palloc, not malloc!
    result = palloc(size);

    --set size of result varlena type
    SET_VARSIZE(result, size);

    -- set data
    memcpy(VARDATA(result), str, hello_size);
    memcpy(VARDATA(result) + hello_size, 
           VARDATA_ANY(txt), VARSIZE_ANY_EXHDR(txt));

    -- returns data
    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(result);
}
```

You can see, this is C and it is not C. There are lot of macros, than can be used a) for portability purposes, b) for hiding complexity. It is good to start to read [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/xfunc-c.html) or some presentation.

This topic is not too hard or too complex, but it is not intuitive - you cannot to start without reading documentation.